# How to add my ERC20 Token to exchanges so others can trade? Best ways for 2021 and Beyond

Tags: erc-20, exchanges

(To start, I acknowledge there are some q&a's on this topic already, but I found they are roughly 3+ years old.)

I have an ERC20 token launching alongside a dapp and I'd like to be able to have it on some minor exchanges for users to trade. Perhaps platforms such as pancakeswap or uniswap or even poocoin (lol). Then ideally I'd want users to be able to see the balance of said token in their mainstream wallets, e.g. with a ticker and small image; for example, adding SHIB to Trustwallet via contract address.

So when I have the smart contract completed, and I've deployed it to the mainnet, what would I do next to achieve these goals? Guidance much appreciated :)

Comment: You need to find the answer and think about those things before start implementing your token. You need to *understand* how DEX like uniswap works and also research on marketing and how to distribute your token to people who won't sell it directly. Short summary *please do MORE research this is only the direction* a pool need to be created it and inside it should be a big amount of the created token and big amount of WEther or other token.. it must be 50% 50%  and this will determinate the start price of the token... etc... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cizLhxSKrAc

Comment: Those protocols like uniswap are also on test chains so you can test them there to understand them more.
I think the part about the image and ticker and automatic recognition of your token probably depends on each wallet.